# SHGO doesn't take equality constraints into account

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, shgo

I'm trying to understand how [`shgo`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html) has to be used. In the following example, I would expect that no solution can be found, because the constraint function always returns 1.0 even though it's supposed to be equal to zero. However, `shgo` terminates successfully:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import shgo
>>> shgo(func=lambda x: -x.sum(), bounds=[(0, 1)]*5, constraints=({'type':'eq','fun': lambda x: 1.0}))
     fun: -5.0
    funl: array([-5.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 39
     nit: 2
   nlfev: 6
   nlhev: 0
   nljev: 1
 success: True
       x: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
      xl: array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

How are constraint functions meant to be used?

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16260